# HTML Geolocation API not working in chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, geolocation, google-chrome-app

After updating `chrome mobile to version 81.0.4044.117`, HTML geolocation API is not at all working.

I tried it on a secure connection (https://)

tried accessing from different demo sites (all are on secure connections)

It was working fine on the previous version and desktop `version 81.0.4044.122`.

here is the demo link

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

here is code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi could you share your code? it will be helpful for debugging or so.

Comment: File a bug, if you're sure that's one?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar I updated the question with code

Comment: @JeremyThille I don't have much knowledge filing bugs